# Angular 8 elements @Input() For Initial Binding Not Working

Tags: angular

I have created an Angular project using elements and built and host the project by using IIS. Then i imported this project to a local project(called 'main-project') by using below codes.

```
<script src="http://localhost:126/child-micro.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:126/child-micro.css" />
```

And I have tried to provide inputs from the main-project to element project like this.

**AppComponent (main-project)**

```
 import { Component, ChangeDetectorRef, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
    import { MatTableDataSource } from "@angular/material";
    import { CollateralDetailsComponent } from "./collateral-details/collateral-details.component";
    import { QuestionsAndAnswersComponent } from "./questions-and-answers/questions-and-answers.component";
    
    const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [];
    @Component({
      selector: "app-root",
      templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
      styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"],
    })
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    
      public components;
      public referenceSubItemId: number;
      public workflowProcessId: number = 3;
      constructor(private changeDetectorRefs: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
    
      public ngOnInit() {
        const microChild: any = document.querySelector("wml-workflow-manager");
        microChild.id = this.workflowProcessId;
      }
    
    }
```

**HTML (main-project)**

```
  <wml-workflow-manager></wml-workflow-manager>
```

But the element project doesn't take the input(workflowProcessId)

Necessary code snippets of the element project are given below

**AppModule(Element project)**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    WorkflowManagerComponent,
  
  ],
  imports: [
   
  ],
  providers: [
  ],
  //exports: [WorkflowManagerComponent],
  entryComponents: [
    WorkflowManagerComponent
  ], // make sure all your components listed here
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {}

  ngDoBootstrap(): any {
    const elements: any[] = [
      [WorkflowManagerComponent, 'wml-workflow-manager'], 
    ];
    for (const [component, name] of elements) {
      const el = createCustomElement(component, { injector: this.injector });
      customElements.define(name, el);
    }
  }
```

**Index.html(Element project)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Template</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </head>
  <body class="mat-typography">
    <wml-workflow-manager></wml-workflow-manager>
  </body>
</html>
```

So, what did i miss ?

Thanks...!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using ngAfterViewInit, try to use ngOnChanges for the Angular element component. That works for me.